# Should I use precondition checks to check intermediate results?

Tags: java, guava

Guava offers helper functions to check the preconditions but I could not find helper functions to check intermediate results.

```
private void foo(String param)
{
    checkNotNull(param, "Required parameter is not set");

    int x = get(param);
    if (x == -1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("This should never have happened and indicates a bug.");
    }
}
```

- Should I wrap the `if (...) {....}` part in my own helper?
- Or should I use `checkState` from Guava?
- Or should I view the failure of `get()` as a consequence of `param` and use `checkArgument`?
- Should I use asserts in these cases?
- Or am I missing something?

Comment: The way your code checks the data is quite valid, however you might want to use a more 'concrete' exception than `RuntimeException` - perhaps `IllegalStateException`, or one of your own.

Comment: Typically, a *"This should never have happened"* exception should be an AssertionError, rather than a RuntimeException. Using assert is a bit fragile as it relies on the JVM arguments... Apart from that your code looks fine to me.

Comment: It seems that getting -1 as a result of working with the argument is a valid `IllegalArgumentException`, therefore I would use `checkArgument(x !- -1, "my message")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's somewhere between a matter of preference and a matter of convention.

Generally, people will use asserts to indicate programming errors; that is, "if I did my job right, then a non-null `param` should *never* result in a -1 from `get`, regardless of user input or other outside forces." I treat them almost as comments that can optionally be verified at runtime.

On the other hand, if `get` might return -1 in some cases, but that input is invalid, then I would generally throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, and `checkArgument` is a perfectly reasonable way to do this. One drawback this has is that when you later catch that, it could have come from pretty much anywhere. Consider:

```
try {
    baz();
    bar();
    foo(myInput);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // Where did this come from!?
    // It could have come from foo(myInput), or baz(), or bar(),
    // or some method that any of them invoked, or really anywhere
    // in that stack.
    // It could be something totally unrelated to user input, just
    // a bug somewhere in my code.
    // Handle it somehow...
}
```

In cases where that matters -- for instance, you want to pop up a helpful note to the user that they're not allowed to enter `-1` in their input form -- you may want to throw a custom exception so that you can more easily catch it later:

```
try {
    baz();
    bar();
    foo(myInput);
} catch (BadUserInputException e) {
    reportError("Bad input: " + e.getMessage());
    log.info("recorded bad user input", e);
}
```

As for `checkState`, it doesn't really sound right to me. That exception usually implies that the problem was the state that `this` was in (or some other, more global state in the application). From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html?is-external=true):

> Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time.

In your case, a -1 is never appropriate, so `checkState` is misleading. Now, if it had been:

```
if (x == -1 && (!allowNegativeOne()) { ... }
```

...then that would be more appropriate, though it still has the drawback that `IllegalArgumentException` had above.

So, lastly, there's the question of whether you should just keep the `if` as it is, or use a helper method. That really comes down to taste, how complex the check is, and how often it's used (e.g. in other methods). If the check is as simple as `x == -1` and that check isn't ever performed by other methods (so code reuse is not an issue), I would just keep the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

If the `get` method is simply converting the string to an int, then it should do the validation there, preferably throwing an illegalArgumentException or some such RuntimeException.  With the above you are also mixing levels of abstraction in your method.  E.g. your `checkNotNull` abstracts away the checking of `param` for null, but the checking for `param` as an int is split across the `get` method and the `foo` method.  Why not have one checkPreCondition type method?  E.g.

```
private void paramShouldBeNonNullInt(String value) {
    if (value == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("value was null");
    try {
       Integer.parseInt(value)
    } catch (NumberFormatException  e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("value was not an integer");
    }
}
```

Comment: `get` is just an example, please ignore it semantics, also the `checkNotNull` is there as an example of what I would like the `if (...)` part to look like, in essence I am just missing an `checkOrThrowRuntime()` function or maybe `checkState` is what I really want.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to make a distinction between contracts (e.g assertions/programming errors) and error handling (e.g. recoverable exceptions that could and should be caught and recovered from).

If you have the need to check an intermediate result, it seems like you don't trust the invoked service and you want to make sure your assumptions hold. Right? This should be expressed as an assertion, and Guava don't have very good support for that.

Have a look at valid4j. Found here https://github.com/helsing/valid4j and here http://www.valid4j.org.

I would then have expressed the code like this (using valid4j's support for hamcrest-matchers):

```
private int getFoo(String param) {
    require(param, notNullValue()); // Violation means programming error at client

    int x = get(param);

    ensure(x, not(equalTo(-1)); // Violation means programming error at supplier
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other excellent answers here.

From the Preconditions [javadoc](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html):

*Precondition exceptions are used to signal that the* calling method *has made an error. (...) Postcondition or other invariant failures should not throw these types of exceptions.*

So ...

> Should I wrap the if (...) {....} part in my own helper?

No, existing facilities should be good enough.

> Or should I use checkState from Guava?

Yes possibly: if parameters need to be loaded from a file before this method is called, then that would be part of the contract of how this class must be used.

> Or should I view the failure of get() as a consequence of param and use checkArgument?

Yes possibly: e.g. if there was some formatting restriction on the syntax of parameters. (Although perhaps that would go inside `get()`)

> Should I use asserts in these cases?

Yes. If it's not a precondition check like the above, then normally I'd just use an `assert` here. Don't forget you can still add a message:

```
assert x != 1 : "Indicates a bug.";
```

I find this appropriate to document expectations and verify the internal / private implementation of a class or method.

If you want to make that a runtime check, you *could* do `if (...) throw AssertionError` but that's probably only necessary if you're working with dodgy code that you don't trust.